# JPA/Hibernate. How to get child objects contained in a list of Parent object using createQuery method

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

I have Certificate class that contains list of Tag classes

```
import javax.persistence.*;
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Objects;

@Entity
@Table(name = "gift_certificate")
public class Certificate {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private String description;
    private BigDecimal price;
    private Integer duration;
    @Column(name = "create_date")
    private LocalDateTime createDate;
    @Column(name = "last_update_date")
    private LocalDateTime lastUpdateDate;
    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(name = "gift_certificate_tag",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "tag_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "gift_certificate_id")
    )
    private List<Tag> tags;
    
getters and setters and other code...
```

....

```
import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.Objects;

@Entity
@Table(name = "tag")
public class Tag {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    private String name;

getters and setters and other code...
```

And I'm trying to get List of Certificate from DB using JPA/Hibernate.
I'm using `EntityManager`

```
public List<Tag> getCertificateTags(Long certificateId) {
    return entityManager.createQuery("select c.tags from Certificate c where c.id=:id")
            .setParameter("id", certificateId)
            .getResultList();
}
```

And it works, but I get just list, not List and IDEA is warning `Unchecked assignment: 'java.util.List' to 'java.util.List<Tag>'`.
And when I use `createQuery` with second parameter `Tag.class` like this:

```
entityManager.createQuery("select c.tags from Certificate c where c.id=:id", Tag.class)
                .setParameter("id", certificateId)
                .getResultList();
```

I get `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Type specified for TypedQuery [Tag] is incompatible with query return type [interface java.util.Collection]`

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to change the query this way

```
select t from Certificate c join c.tags t where c.id=:id
```

The reason is that `select c.tags` means every result row contains **a list of tags**. But when you `select t from Certificate c join c.tags t` every row contains  **one tag**